# Pandas Converter on Data strptime()

Tags: python

I am trying to plot this points, however I am getting that error. Do I need another converter for the date data? The x-axis should be the date, and y axis should be the time value. Thank you.

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=[0], header=None,
                         names=['Date', 'Time'])

print (df.head())
        Date         Time
0 2015-01-02  02:29:45 PM
1 2015-01-02  05:16:15 PM
2 2015-01-02  05:48:46 PM
3 2015-01-02  03:18:34 PM
4 2015-01-02  05:22:55 PM
In [5]:

date = df['Date']
time = df['Time']

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
​
​
def date_to_days(date):
    return date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d'))
​
​
def time_to_hours(time):
    [hh, mm, ss] = [int(x) for x in time.split(':')]
    seconds = datetime.timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm, seconds=ss).seconds
    hours = seconds / float(3600)
    return hours
​
if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_date = '2015-01-01'
    end_date = '2015-01-31'
​
    dates = date
    times = time
​
    days = [date_to_days(d) for d in dates]
    hours = [time_to_hours(t) for t in times]
​
    plt.plot_date(days, hours, ydate=False)
    plt.axis([date_to_days(start_date), date_to_days(end_date), 0, 24])
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Time (hours)')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime.strptime()` is for *parsing* strings into `datetime.datetime` objects. As such it makes no sense to apply it to a `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` object, which is what would be passed in by `[date_to_days(d) for d in dates]` because `dates` contains those objects.

It should be possible to pass the pandas timestamp directly to `date2num()`:

```
def date_to_days(date):
    return date2num(date)

>>> days = [date_to_days(d) for d in dates]
>>> days
[735600.0, 735600.0, 735600.0, 735600.0, 735600.0]
```

Later in your code you want to call `date2num()` on date strings, however, you could simply define them upfront as `datetime` objects so as to avoid parsing the strings:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31)
```

and this will work with the revised function that I show above; in fact the `date_to_days()` function is no longer required.... just call `date2num()` directly:

```
days = [date2num(d) for d in dates]
```

and

```
plt.axis([date2num(start_date), date2num(end_date), 0, 24])
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be that you assume `df['Date']` is a string column and you're trying to convert it to date with `[date_to_days(d) for d in dates]`, but since you read the file with the `parse_dates=[0]` option, pandas already parsed it.